# Have kwikset deadbolt with interior knob with setscrew is not coming off after setscrew has been removed why?

Tags: doors, lock

Kwikset deadbolt interior knob with set screw removed yet knob will not come off, what else can I do to remove the knob?

Comment: Can we have some photos of the situation please?

Comment: The knob on a deadbolt  does not have a set screw, are you talking about a door knob or a deadbolt?

Answer (score 1):

**Deadbolt:** I’m assuming what you call the “set screw” refers to the two long mounting screws on the inside side of the door lock, by the thumb turn assembly.

[image: kwikset mounting schematic]

You should be able to remove those two long screws and the thumb turn plate should come right off. The lock cylinder assembly on the front of the door should then be removable. Finally, when the front and rear are removed, the deadbolt mechanism can be removed from the side of the door.

If the rear or front don’t easily come off, often it’s because they were painted over or applied when the door paint was fresh. A very gentle rap with a non-marring hammer should knock them off. I often just use a block of wood to soften the blow and rap gently.

You can also try to cut the seal or pry them off with a razor but it’s easy to mar the surface of the door.

---

**Knob or handle:** if you’re instead referring to a locking doorknob, you again remove the two mounting screws (they’re not easily visible in the schematic below but they’re roughly in the same place and roughly the same length as the deadbolt above) and the handle assembly should pull right off.

[image: handle schematic]

There’s no need to try to remove the handle from its base.

Again if it feels stuck, it may be glued on because it was painted over or applied in wet paint. A gentle tap with a non-marring hammer or block of wood should take it off.

Note: both sets of schematics from Kwikset’s website. Fair use claimed.

Comment: There's probably two tiny set screws that only hold the handle on. Underneath that is the two bolts. If the OP's removed all of those, tap it with a hammer, +1

Comment: I don’t think there’s a door handle on the deadbolt unless it’s a handle and deadbolt single unit. The thumb turn itself is usually not designed to be taken off its mounting plate.

Comment: [thumbturn mounting screws](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/157203843222891828) - Good locks are usually not designed the way Kwiksets are ;)

Comment: Kwikset and good lock don’t belong in the same sentence unless there’s a negative in there somewhere.